# c# httpclient returns 400 error when javascript version is 201

Tags: c#, header, httpclient

I have a working javscript example to send a `post` request.

```
  var payload = { market: req.body.market, order: { price: req.body.order.price, side: req.body.order.side, size: req.body.order.size } };
  var headers = {
        'cx-api-key': apiKey,
        'cx-content-hash': contentHash,
        'cx-timestamp': timestamp,
        'cx-signature': signature
    };

  axios.post('https://test.com/orders', payload, { headers: headers })
        .then(function (response) {
            if (response.status === 201) {
                res.sendStatus(201);                    
            }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            res.status(500).send({ error: error });
        });
```

Now converting this to c#, I did

```
 var payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(vm);
 var client = new HttpClient();
 var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage
 {
      Method = HttpMethod.Post,
      RequestUri = new Uri("https://test.com/orders"),
      Headers = {          
         { "cx-api-key", apiKey },
         { "cx-content-hash", contentHash },
         { "cx-timestamp", timestamp.ToString() },
         { "cx-signature", signature }
       },
       Content = new StringContent(payload)
 };
 var response = await client.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);
```

I checked that `apikey`, `contentHash`, `timestamp`, `signature` and `payload` values matching with javascript version.
Any idea why i'm getting 400? I'm assuming because `timestamp` in header is converted to string value. But I know that it should be transmitted as a text value over http.

Comment: The format of `timestamp` is proably different.

Comment: Try the overload of StringContent that takes an encoding and mime type.

Comment: By the way, the latest version of ECMAScript (javascript) is 10, so you're definitely not using version 201.

Comment: @John, that's an http status code

Comment: Any suggestion for encoding and mime type?

Comment: with `new StringContent(payload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")` it's still the same

Comment: @John what do you mean by the format of `timestamp` is different?

Comment: Are you familiar with Fiddler? You can trace the network  and see the difference between the two operations. Also, if there is a difference in the headers you should be able to see it in the debugger.

Comment: If timestamp is a `DateTime` in C# and a Date in Javascript, then the result of converting both of those to a string in the default way will be different.